# Day Long Word Chain

Tags: word-ladder

What is the least amount of words you can use in a word chain when starting from "Dawn", using "Noon" in the middle, and finishing with "Dusk", and using only 4 letter words? Please try to stick to "regular" words (i.e. something found in the dictionary or that would be used in a crossword, no abbreviations).

Example word chain:
Hear

Bear

Beat

Feat

Feet

Fret

Etc....

Comment: By "in the middle" do you mean it has to be *exactly* in the middle, or just anywhere inside the ladder?

Comment: @JaapScherphuis Anywhere in the ladder between Dawn and Dusk

Comment: You have to be more specific about what’s considered a “regular” word, since otherwise the answer can vary depending on the dictionary/crossword clue service that is used

Answer (score 4):

Here is a chain with 8 letter changes (edited question)

> Dawn
>  Down
>  [Doon](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/doon)
>  Noon
>  Nook
>  Nock
>  Dock
>  Duck
>  Dusk
>  Could also replace Doon with [Nown](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/nown)

Here is a chain with 5 letter changes (original question)

> Dawn
>  Darn
>  Dark
>  Dack
>  Duck
>  Dusk

Comment: Check my edited question, I decided to add a small challenge :)

Comment: @ThatOneNerdyBoy That **completely** changes the question...

Comment: @Avi I am aware, I merely forgot to add that middle requirement. That's my bad!

Answer (score 1):

12 changes:

> DAWN -> DOWN -> GOWN -> GOON -> NOON -> NOOK -> NORK -> DORK -> DARK -> BARK -> BASK -> BUSK -> DUSK

Comment: Check my edited question, I decided to add a small challenge :)

Comment: @ThatOneNerdyBoy please don't make substantial changes to questions after posting, and even more so if the question has already been answered. The Stack Exchange model breaks down if you do that, resulting in upvoted answers not matching the question, and legit answers being downvoted because they answer a different question. This is a bit less important on other sites, but on PSE, changing the required answer is pretty drastic.

Comment: @Bass I understand and will take this into account in the future!